# Power user access to Sitecore Recycle Bin

Tags: sitecore

Does anyone know of a solution to allow users in a certain role to view all items in the Sitecore Recycle Bin?

Currently, only admins can see all deleted items.  Users can only see items they have deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way out of the box, the `SqlArchive.GetEntries` checks against `user.IsAdministrator` to show all entries in the archive.

You would need to implement a custom Archive provider and override the **GetEntries** method to work from a role.

Example:

```cs
public class CustomSqlArchive : SqlArchive
{
    public CustomSqlArchive(string name, Database database)
        : base(name, database)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ArchiveEntry> GetEntries(User user, int pageIndex, int pageSize, ID archivalId)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(archivalId, "archivalId");
        var arrayList = new ArrayList(new[] { "archiveName", this.Name });
        var str1 = "SELECT * FROM \r\n          (SELECT {0}Archive{1}.{0}ArchivalId{1}, {0}Archive{1}.{0}ItemId{1}, {0}ParentId{1}, {0}Name{1}, {0}OriginalLocation{1}, \r\n            {0}ArchiveDate{1}, {0}ArchivedBy{1}, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {0}ArchiveDate{1} DESC, {0}ArchivalId{1}) as {0}RowNumber{1}\r\n              FROM {0}Archive{1} \r\n           WHERE {0}ArchiveName{1} = {2}archiveName{3}";

        var showAllItems = user.IsInRole("Super User Role") || user.IsAdministrator;

        if (user != null && !showAllItems)
        {
            str1 = str1 + " AND {0}ArchivalId{1} IN (SELECT {0}ArchivalId{1}\r\n          FROM {0}ArchivedVersions{1} WHERE {0}ArchivedBy{1} = {2}archivedBy{3}) ";
            arrayList.AddRange(new[] { "archivedBy", user.Name });
        }

        if (archivalId != ID.Null)
        {
            str1 = str1 + " AND {0}ArchivalId{1} = {2}archivalId{3}";
            arrayList.Add("archivalId");
            arrayList.Add(archivalId);
        }

        var str2 = str1 + ") {0}ArchiveWithRowNumbers{1}";
        if (pageSize != int.MaxValue)
        {
            str2 = str2 + " WHERE {0}RowNumber{1} BETWEEN {2}firstRow{3} AND {2}lastRow{3}";
            var num1 = (pageIndex * pageSize) + 1;
            int num2 = pageSize == int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (pageIndex + 1) * pageSize;
            arrayList.AddRange(new[] { "firstRow", num1.ToString(), "lastRow", num2.ToString() });
        }

        return this.GetEntries(str2 + " ORDER BY {0}ArchiveDate{1} DESC, {0}ArchivalId{1}", arrayList.ToArray());
    }
}
```

You would then need to add your custom provider to the config:

```
<archives defaultProvider="custom" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="custom" type="Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchiveProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" database="*" />
        <add name="sql" type="Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchiveProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" database="*" />
        <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SwitchingArchiveProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    </providers>
</archives>
```

Then add a role called Super User Role and put any users you want to have that access as members.

** note - code is untested **

Answer (score 1):

Below is a similar approach to Richard's answer, but instead of copying all of the logic within `GetEntries()`, it spoofs the admin user. You will also need to implement a `SqlArchiveProvider` in addition to the `CustomSqlArchive` itself.

**SQL Archive**

```
public class CustomSqlArchive : SqlArchive
{
    private const string PowerUserRole = @"sitecore\Power User";
    private const string AdminUser = @"sitecore\Admin";

    public AvidSqlArchive(string name, Database database) : base(name, database) { }

    protected override IEnumerable<ArchiveEntry> GetEntries(User user, int pageIndex, int pageSize, ID archivalId)
    {
        if (user != null && Role.Exists(PowerUserRole) && user.IsInRole(PowerUserRole))
        {
            User admin = User.FromName(AdminUser, true);
            return base.GetEntries(admin, pageIndex, pageSize, archivalId);
        }

        return base.GetEntries(user, pageIndex, pageSize, archivalId);
    }
}
```

**SQL Archive Provider**

```
public class CustomSqlArchiveProvider : SqlArchiveProvider
{
    protected override Sitecore.Data.Archiving.Archive GetArchive(XmlNode configNode, Database database)
    {
        string attribute = XmlUtil.GetAttribute("name", configNode);
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute) ?
            new CustomSqlArchive(attribute, database) :
            null;
    }
}
```

**Configuration Patch**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>

    <!-- Use custom archive that allows users in the "Power User" role to see other user's items by spoofing the admin user -->
    <archives defaultProvider="sql" enabled="true">
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">custom</patch:attribute>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="custom" type="Example.CustomSqlArchiveProvider, Example" database="*" />
        <add name="sql" type="Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchiveProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" database="*" />
        <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SwitchingArchiveProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      </providers>
    </archives>

  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```